# Breadcrumbs with a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

What might be the reason my breadcrumbs aren't shown on the page when the address is like http://localhost:53732/Details/Index/1
[image]

But it works if I manually rewrite the address like this
http://localhost:53732/Details/Index?id=1
[image]

Here is my Mvc.sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="true">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Listing" controller="Listing" action="Listing" key="Details">
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

And here is the method which returns my View Details/Index:

```
namespace OurNewShop.Controllers
{
    public class DetailsController : Controller
    {
        [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "DetailsPage", ParentKey = "Details")]
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            using (ProductContext context = new ProductContext())
            {
                Product pr = context.Products.Include(y => y.ProductImages).FirstOrDefault(y => y.ProductId == id);
                ViewBag.ImagePath = Constants.Constants.ImagePath;
                return View(pr);
             });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the solution to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters must be mentioned in mvcSiteMapNode within web.sitemap in order to make the breadcrumbs and navigation work properly. Try including "id", and "preservedRouteParameters" as shown below.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" id="*" preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
```

Comment: then should I write [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "DetailsPage", ParentKey = "Details")] before public ActionResult Index(int id)?

Comment: and do I have to specify id?

Comment: thank you, adding   preservedRouteParameters="id" and deleting  [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "DetailsPage", ParentKey = "Details")]  helped me!

Comment: Glad it worked... yes, id is just a name of the parameter, if you have multiple parameters in your route, then you would need to specify them as well.